# Election page shows property / method chain instead of actual information

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

When I access the [Android.SE election page](https://android.stackexchange.com/election), I see:

[image]

I'm sorry, but I don't know what `!Current.Site.Settings.Reputation.NeededForModeratorVote.Full()` means.

Comment: It most likely means someone typed `!` instead of `@`, but that's probably not the answer you were looking for. :P

Comment: @TimStone My C# knowledge fails me. What does `@` do?

Comment: It starts a code block in a Razor template, which would have shown you the output of that code instead of the code itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has already been fixed for the next build.